# Is this second multicolumn unique key in my MySQL statement redundant or does it improve performance?

Tags: mysql

I found this old code and I'm not sure if it's optimized or just doing something silly.

I have a SQL create statement like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_pmpro_memberships_categories` (
  `membership_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY `membership_category` (`membership_id`,`category_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `category_membership` (`category_id`,`membership_id`)
);
```

Is that second UNIQUE KEY there redundant with the PRIMARY KEY on the same 2 columns? Or would the second one help for queries that filter by the category_id first then by the membership_id? Is it being ignored?

I'm trying to remember why I coded it that way, way back when. Seems similar to what this comment is describing: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1793/245678

Thanks!

Comment: Without knowing all your use cases it is impossible to say for sure but many, if not most, junction tables benefit from both indices, although there is no need for the unique constraint on the second index as this overhead is already covered by the primary key.

Comment: That SE link is only partially relevant.

Comment: @nnichols - _In my opinion_, a Junction table will eventually be used in both directions, so you may as well have both indexes.

Comment: @RickJames Your opinion carries some weight ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your query patterns. If you do `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` only on the `category_id` column, then the 2nd index makes sense but you should omit the `membership_id` column (redundant) and the `UNIQUE` constraint.

MySQL will automatically use the `PRIMARY KEY` index if you use either `membership_id` or both columns. It doesn't matter in which order these columns appear in your `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

- The secondary index *does* improve performance when going from a "category" to a "membership".
- You coded it with those two indexes because some queries start with a "membership" and need to locate a "category"; some queries go the 'other' direction.
- That's a well-coded "many-to-many mapping table".
- InnoDB provides better performance than MyISAM.
- The "Uniqueness" constraint in the `UNIQUE` key is redundant.
- Checking for Uniqueness slows dowing *writes* by a very small amount.  (The constraint must be checked before finishing the update to the index's BTree.  A non-unique index can put off the update until later; see "change buffering".)
- I like to say this to indicate that I have some reason for the *pair* of columns being together in the index:

  ```
  INDEX(`category_id`,`membership_id`)
  ```
- I discuss the schema pattern here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table